# Class Dynamic Array Bug

Tags: c++, arrays, class, logic

I am required to implement a dynamic array that adjusts, dynamically, in accordance with the number of value (temperatures) that are input into the code. I have written the majority of the code for this to be possible, however I have run into a bug and for the life of me, have been unable to locate the issue.

The program is supposed to output the values of temp_a, make temp_b = temp_a, output the value of temp_b, and then clear the value of temp_a, and finally output the values of temp_b once more.

However, when I compile the program, it outputs that the list is full and cannot add any more values, meaning there is a logic error somewhere in the code.

Please forgive me for the lengthy code, as soon as I can locate the error, the code shall be separated into multiple compilations.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TemperatureList {
private:
    int* temp;  // pointer to dynamic array
    short current_size;     // current number of elements
    short max_size; // max number of elements allowed in this list
public:
    // Overloading assignment operator
    void operator =(const TemperatureList& another_list);

    // === Constructors ===
    // Default constructor
    TemperatureList();
    // Constructor that accepts an integer parameter that specifies the max length of the list
    TemperatureList(int max);
    // Copy constructor that accepts another List as parameter
    TemperatureList(const TemperatureList& another_list);
    // Destructor
    ~TemperatureList();

    // === Modifier functions ===
    // add new_value to end of list if there is still space
    void add_temperature(int new_value);

    // === Accessor functions ===
    // return current current_size of the list
    short get_current_size();

    // === Other functions ===  
    // return the last element, or 0 if the list is empty, with a warning output
    int get_last();
    // return element at the position-th position, or 0 if the list is empty, with a warning output
    int get_temp(short position);
    // returns if current_size == 0
    bool set_temp(short position, int value);
    // returns if current_size == 0
    bool empty();
    // returns if current_size == max_size
    bool full();
    // Output list separated by commas
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const TemperatureList& list);
};

int main() {
    TemperatureList temp_a;

    temp_a.add_temperature(23.5);
    temp_a.add_temperature(24.6);
    cout << temp_a;

    TemperatureList temp_b = temp_a;
    cout << temp_b;

    temp_a = TemperatureList();
    cout << "Now there's no temperatures in a.\n";
    cout << temp_a;
    cout << "How about temperatures in b?\n";
    cout << temp_b;

    return 0;
}

void TemperatureList::operator =(const TemperatureList& another_list) {
    delete[] temp;
    current_size = another_list.current_size;
    max_size = another_list.max_size;
    if (current_size > 0) {
        temp = new int[max_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++) {
            temp[i] = another_list.temp[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        temp = NULL;
    }
}
TemperatureList::TemperatureList() {
    current_size = 0;
    max_size = 0;
    temp = NULL;
}
TemperatureList::TemperatureList(int max) : max_size(max) {
    current_size = 0;
    temp = new int[max];
}
TemperatureList::TemperatureList(const TemperatureList& another_list) {
    current_size = another_list.current_size;
    max_size = another_list.max_size;
    if (current_size > 0) {
        temp = new int[max_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < max_size; i++) {
            temp[i] = another_list.temp[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        temp = NULL;
    }
}
TemperatureList::~TemperatureList() {
    //cout << "== I am in destructor ==\n";
    delete[] temp;
}

void TemperatureList::add_temperature(int new_value) {
    if (current_size < max_size) {
        temp[current_size] = new_value;
        current_size++;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Cannot add value to the list. It is full.\n";
    }
}
int TemperatureList::get_last() {
    if (empty()) {
        cout << "The list is empty\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return temp[current_size - 1];
    }
}
int TemperatureList::get_temp(short position) {
    if (current_size >= position) {
        return temp[position - 1];
    }
    else {
        cout << "There is no temperature\n";
        return 0;
    }
}
bool TemperatureList::set_temp(short position, int value) {
    if (current_size >= position) {
        temp[position - 1] = value;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
short TemperatureList::get_current_size() {
    return current_size;
}
bool TemperatureList::empty() {
    return (current_size == 0);
}
bool TemperatureList::full() {
    return (current_size == max_size);
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& outs, const TemperatureList& list) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (list.current_size - 1); i++) {
        outs << list.temp[i] << ",";
    }
    outs << list.temp[i];
    return outs;
}
```

Comment: Maybe for you this code is outputting that the list is full, but for me, the code you've posted crashes, because you're constructing the temperature list with the default constructor, which sets `temp` to null. If `temp` is `nullptr` and you try and deference it (`temp[n]` or `*temp` or `temp->`) you will get a segmentation fault and your program will crash. The program will be more robust if you add null checks for `temp` to some of these methods.

Answer (score 2):

The logic error seems to stem from the fact that you initialize your current_size and max_size to zero. So, unless your run the overloaded constructor (wherein you’re set the max_size), every call to addTemperature() is going to fail the (current_size < max_size) check because they are both equal to zero.